# "Object Not Found!" OSX, Silex and XAMPP development environment

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, silex

I have been struggling with setting up a PHP/MySQL environment all day and thought I would finally ask for help.

I have XAMPP up and running. In order to work in my preferred directory I've updated `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` with:

```
User MY_USERNAME

...

DocumentRoot "/Users/PATH/TO/WORKING/DIR/web"
<Directory "/Users/PATH/TO/WORKING/DIR/web">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # XAMPP
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None
    # since XAMPP 1.4:
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Otherwise my `httpd.conf` settings are the XAMPP defaults. In my `web` dir, I have index.php:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get("/", function () {
    return "Hello World";
});

$app->get("/test", function () {
    return "Success";
});

$app->run();

?>
```

If I go to `localhost`, I get the expected "Hello World." However, if I go to `localhost/test` I get:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
>   Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

This is a much simplified example, but illustrates the problem.

I've scoured the Google results for this error, but none of the recommended suggestions have helped:

- Lots of people suggest I update `.htaccess`, but I don't know where that is in XAMPP or where I should create it or what I should put in it or what it is.
- Recommendation of changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in `httpd.conf` didn't seem to work. (I reverted this back to the default settings after confirming that it didn't help)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for your time!

**SOLUTION**

I had created `.htaccess` in `/Users/PATH/TO/WORKING/DIR/todo` where I needed to put it in `/Users/PATH/TO/WORKING/DIR/todo/web` where I was pointing XAMPP to. Then inside of `.htaccess` I put the stuff Silex told me to put in there: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/web_servers.html

Comment: You need rewriting. Seems you want localhost/test to be a call to your index.php. So far I cannot see anything in your configuration that would cause apache to react that way. .htaccess files reside in any folder reachable via your apache configuration, see eg. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
With that you could control the rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` needs to be at the root of your web application, so in `web`. Create it if it doesn't exist. It should contain  what's indicated here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/web_servers.html

`AllowOverride All` is indeed needed but if you don't have any `.htaccess` file in your web app folder, there's 0 chance it's gonna work.

Comment: This worked! I had put the .htaccess file in `/PATH/project_folder` when I needed to put in `/PATH/project_folder/web` where I was pointing XAMPP to I guess. Thank you!

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer (as soon as Stackoverflow allows you to do so) if it solved your problem :-)

Comment: Upvoted and accepted (although my upvote isn't counted by Stack Overflow yet)